# Correctly securing websockets per user

Tags: asp.net, websocket, oauth-2.0

I have implemented websockets in my application but currently I see a potential security flaw.

The websocket is designed to send data for a particular user's account to the browser but the server needs to know the `AccountID` of the user to do this.  Currently I just send the `AccountId` as a queryString parameter from the front end but this is obviously open for abuse as anyone could artificially change their `AccountID`.

I currently use `ApplicationOAuthProvider` in the ASP.NET backend for WebAPI authentication but I wasn't able to use this with the WebSocket request as when I set the Bearer token it failed. As such I've had to set my WebSocket handshake call to be anonymous

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/realtime")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RealTime()
{
    var currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

    if (currentContext.IsWebSocketRequest || currentContext.IsWebSocketRequestUpgrading)
    {
        currentContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest(this.ProcessWebSocketRequest);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

**WebSocketHandler**

```
public override void OnOpen()
{
    this.AccountId = int.Parse(this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["accountId"]);

    if (this.myClientService.ClusterClient == null)
    {
        this.myClientService
            .Start()
            .ContinueWith(async (t) =>
            {
                await this.myClient.OnWebSocketConnected(this.AccountId, this);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        var unawaitedTask = this.myClient.OnWebSocketConnected(this.AccountId, this);
    }
}
```

How is this commonly solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single-use token for this, as follows:

First, the client makes an HTTP call with a bearer token in the authentication header, as a means of authorization or authentication. In response, your application returns a URL for establishing a websocket connection. This URL may look like "wss://domain.name/connect/374623618723232372". That long random number is a single-use token, which you generate on demand and and store in your database, associating it with the authorization or authentication context (e.g. it could be the user ID, or any roles or permissions granted to the user).

Next, the client establishes a websocket connection with your application using that URL. When this happens, your application extracts that single-use token from the URL, verifies in the database that it hasn't been used yet, reads the authorization / authentication context, and removes it from the database.

This way you uniquely link the websocket session to the OAuth session.